# Docker contain opens directly into specified conda environment

Tags: docker, conda

I have a Docker container that has two conda environments in it. One is used the vast majority of the time so I would like to automatically start in that environment (currently in starts in the base environment). Based on [this website](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/activate-conda-dockerfile/) I tried by adding this to the end of my Dockerfile:

```
# Activate env
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "py3", "/bin/bash", "-c"]
ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "-n", "py3", "python", "pass.py"]
```

where run.py just contains `print("hello world")`.

This caused the script to run but the docker container does not remain open after I run the docker container, although it does when I remove these lines. How do I get the container to open and stay open in a specified environment?

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.1-cudnn7-devel-centos7

WORKDIR /app/
COPY ./*.* ./
ENV CONDA_DIR "/opt/conda"
ENV PATH "$CONDA_DIR"/bin:$PATH
ONBUILD ENV PATH "$CONDA_DIR"/bin:$PATH

RUN  \
   yum -y install epel-release && \
    yum -y update && \
    yum install -y \
    bzip2 \
    curl \
    which \
    libXext \
    libSM \
    libXrender \
    git \
    cuda-nvcc-10-1 \
    openssh-server \
    postgresql-devel \
    yum clean all && rm -rf /var/cache/yum/*


RUN CONDA_VERSION="4.7.12" && \
    curl -L \
       https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-${CONDA_VERSION}-Linux-x86_64.sh -o miniconda.sh && \
    mkdir -p "$CONDA_DIR" && \
    bash miniconda.sh -f -b -p "$CONDA_DIR" && \
    echo "export PATH=$CONDA_DIR/bin:\$PATH" > /etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
    rm miniconda.sh && \
    conda config --add channels conda-forge && \
    conda config --set auto_update_conda False && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    rm -rf /root/.cache/pip/*


RUN conda env create -f py2_env.yaml
RUN conda env create -f py3_env.yaml

# Activate env
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "py3", "/bin/bash", "-c"]
ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "-n", "py3", "python", "pass.py"]
```

Comment: A Docker container, definitionally, runs a single process and exits.  What do you want the single process to be?  (What would it mean for another kind of process like a Web server to "stay open" after it exited?)

Comment: I want to go inside the container and run a jupyter notebook server. I also want to be able to use the command line.